# SQL SUM GROUP BY two tables

Tags: sql, group-by, sum

I'm having difficulty writing an SQL query that will correctly group account_no together and subtracting an amount.

Firstly I wrote this query which updates everything fine except ACCOUNT_NO A-102 should end up as 4500 not as two different correct balances.

```
select transactions.account_no, account.balance, transactions.amount,
(account.balance + transactions.amount) AS "CORRECT BALANCE"
from transactions, account
where account.account_no = transactions.account_no;

ACCOUNT_NO| BALANCE   | AMOUNT    | CORRECTBALANCE 

A-102     |  4000     |  2000     |  6000                   
A-102     |  4000     |  -1500    |  2500                   
A-222     |  8000     |  -1000    |  7000                   
A-305     |  2000     |  1300     |  3300
```

I tried to sum and group by the account_no but I cannot work out how to do this with the two tables. This was just something I tried but could not get to work.

```
select transactions.account_no, SUM(transactions.amount)
from transactions
group by transactions.account_no;


ACCOUNT_NO| SUM(TRANSACTIONS.AMOUNT) 
A-305     |    1300                     
A-102     |    500                      
A-222     |    -1000
```

The expected outcome should be:

```
ACCOUNT_NO| BALANCE   | AMOUNT    | CORRECTBALANCE 

A-102     |  4000     |  500      |  4500                 
A-222     |  8000     |  -1000    |  7000                   
A-305     |  2000     |  1300     |  3300
```

This is because the account A-102 it has two different amounts coming out, but from the same balance.

Comment: Could two equal account numbers occur with a different balance, eg. "A-102" with balance 4000 and "A-102" with balance 3200?

Comment: No, the balance is meant to be exactly the same. It comes up twice because in the table it's a joint-account so it's in for two different names. It's always meant to be exactly the same.

Comment: I get it. Have you taken a look at my solution for your query?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For your query, to get the two rows grouped on one row, you can try grouping on the account number AND the balance:

```
SELECT  T.account_no
        ,A.balance
        ,SUM(T.amount) AS TotalAmount
        ,(A.balance + SUM(T.amount)) AS "CORRECT BALANCE"
FROM    transactions AS T
INNER JOIN account AS A ON T.account_no = A.account_no
GROUP BY T.account_no, A.balance;
```

(By the way, I've used the ANSI join instead of the 'old' way of joining tables, because it's much more clear what you're doing that way.)

**EDIT**

To make things a bit more clear, I've made a **[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22cf8/2)**. Does this represent your situation more or less correctly?

**EDIT2**

The above query would not show any accounts without transactions, as [Kaf](https://stackoverflow.com/users/412923) commented. That might be what you want, but in case it's not you can switch the join tables like this:

```
SELECT  A.account_no
        ,A.balance
        ,SUM(T.amount) AS TotalAmount
        ,(A.balance + SUM(T.amount)) AS "CORRECT BALANCE"
FROM    account AS A
LEFT OUTER JOIN transactions AS T ON T.account_no = A.account_no
GROUP BY A.account_no, A.balance;
```

Comment: @Sjrsmile: I am not worried you selecting this answer, but according to your table structure, I think best thing is to get the sum from transaction table before joining to avoid unwanted grouping. That was why I removed same answer from my post.. Also, this query won't give you any records for accounts with no records in transaction table.

Comment: @Kaf: you're absolutely right about the records without transactions. I'll add a query that will take care of that (basically switching the join order). As to the sum-before-joining I'm not sure if that is a problem. Can you think of an example where this would go wrong?

Comment: Not wrong, but I think can avoid unwanted grouping by summing first and then joining. Anyways, he has got what he needed in either way and disappeared..

Comment: True... Ah, the hardships of the unloved StackOverflow Army of Volunteers... :-)

Answer (score 3):

Are you looking how to join tables and sum using group by?

First query;

**UPDATE:** I think your *`Account table`* has *1:many* relationship with *`Transaction table`*, so, you should *`get the sum from transaction table`* and then *join* with *`Account`*. Ideally, you need a `left join` as below.

```
select a.account_no, 
       a.balance, 
       isnull(x.amount,0) amount, 
       (a.balance + isnull(x.amount,0)) correctAmount
from account a left join (
           select t.account_no, sum(t.amount) amount
           from transactions t
           group by t.account_no ) x
   on a.account_no = x.account_no
```

[**SQL-FIDDLE-DEMO**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/22cf8/6) (thanks @Josien for tables and data)

Comment: Getting ahead of myself, apologies. That nearly works, but it's also summing up the balance for A-102 twice, while the balance is only 4000, not 8000.<br>

The second query was just showing how I was trying to solve it myself but was having no luck going any further forward.

Comment: I've edited my first comment instead of saying a response, hadn't realised I could add more comments ~ sorry!
This also sums up the balance to 8000 while it just needs to stay at 4000, is there a way to ony sum up the amount and leave the balance alone?

Comment: From the given data: A-102 has two records each 4000 balance. When the sum total = 4000+4000 > 8000? can you update the question with expected results?

Comment: You could try grouping on the account.balance as well in the first query. That way you're not adding up the balances.

Comment: @Josien, for the given data that would be okay, but how about if he had another record for A-102 with balance 3000? I think something is not clear in his question...

Comment: Thanks for being patient, I've updated the question. I hope this makes it more clear?

Comment: @Sjrsmile: I have updated the answer, by looking at your expected results, I think you need `balance + sum(t.amount)`. But I am not sure why I would group by balance.

Comment: That's perfect, thank you both for your help. I'm sorry I couldn't be more clear, but you've done me a service non-the-less. Thanks!

Comment: @Sjrsmile, don't take the first query, it will work only for the given data. Second updated query is the correct one because your account table has 1 to many relation ship with transaction table, so, you should get the sum from transaction and then join with account.

Comment: +1, though it seems like a much more convoluted solution than mine :-)

Comment: @Josien, I new there was some piece of information missing. Thanks for your fiddle... I'll give you +1 for doing that without much info.

Comment: I tried this, but it throws an error "FROM keyword not found where expected" Error on line 3.

Comment: I take that back, what I've tried now works. Excellent work guys!