# Hibernate Join query to fetch the data in Java?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I am new to Hibernate and Java server side. I have mapped MySQL table in Java using `javax.persistence` annotation. I have two tables:

`order_header`
In this table, I have 
`order_number(primary_key),total_order_value,delivery_charge,order_time` columns.

`order_details`
In this table, I have 
`order_number,product_code,price` columns.

In `order_header` the **order_number** is primary key.

For Each **order_number** there are `n` number of products in **order_details** table.
How can I combine both these tables?
What is the Query to get the value like **Final Output**

For Example :

**Order Headers Table**

```
Order_number     total_order_value     delivery_charge      order_time
----------------------------------------------------------------------
   25                2550                     50             03:20:50
   36                350                      50             03:20:50
----------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Order_headers.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_headers")
public class Order_headers {

@Id @GeneratedValue
@Column(name = "order_number")
private int order_number;

@Column(name = "total_order_value")
private double order_value;

@Column(name = "delivery_charge")
private String delivery_charge;

@Column(name = "order_time")
private String order_time;

//here getter and setter methods
}
```

**Order_details**

```
Order_number     product_code     price
---------------------------------------
    25               235          1500
    25               240          1000
    36               50           40
    36               96           60
    36               150          200
```

**Order_details.java**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "order_details")
public class Order_details {

@Column(name = "Order_number")
private int Order_number;

@Column(name = "product_code")
private String product_code;

@Column(name = "price")
private String price;

//here getter and setter methods
}
```

I don't know how to write the combined query in Hibernate to get the details like final output.

**Final Output**

```
Order_number     total_order_value     product_value   delivery_charge      order_time
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   25                2550                   2500             50             03:20:50
   36                350                    300              50             03:20:50
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Please help me to solve this issue.

Comment: You dont need to, hibernate will do this for your. Change type of Order_number in Order_details.java to Order_headers and change field to OneToOne relation. When quering the header obect hibernate will automaticly join the details for you.

Comment: Could you elaborate more on what do you mean by "How to combine and calculate the only products values from order_details table"?

And how do you calculate the value for `product_value` in the Final Output example?

Comment: @SergeyPauk I want the Hibernate query to get **Final output**.

Comment: Clear, what about the second question, how do you calculate product_value from Final output (could your post the SQL query)? I would assume that it's a sum of prices but in this case order 36 sum of prices should end up as 200 not 300.

Comment: @SergeyPauk am entered wrongly when am type.Whats is query to generate the result set like final output.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15109109/sql-sum-group-by-two-tables

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you have to add relationship between Order_headers and Order_details one to many in hibernate you can achieve this by following code in your Order_headers.java

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "Order_number", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
private List<Order_details> orderDetailList;

//add getter and setter methods for orderDetailList.
```

once you add this code now you can write Criteria like

```
Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Order_headers.class);
criteria.setFetchMode("Order_details",FetchMode.JOIN);
List<Order_headers> list = criteria.list();
```

or you can Writer HQL like

```
session.createQuery("from Order_headers cont join cont.Order_details where cont.id=1");
```

or you can also write SQL Query in case you want to writer SQL Query no need of adding property orderDetailList in Order_headers.java here is SQL

```
session.createSQLQuery("SELECT * FROM Order_headers order JOIN Order_details details ON order.order_number = details.order_number");
```

Comment: it shows error `No identifier specified for entity: model.Order_details`

Comment: which option you are using from above three.?  i mean Criteria,HQL or SQL.?

Comment: Thanks.Just now only am also identify that one.How to give where condition in `Criteria`. Because some columns have null values, so it shows error like `Null value was assigned to a property of primitive type setter`

Comment: By the way every class defined as Entity with @Entity annotation, needs an '@Id' or '@EmbeddedId' property.